# VBA Find and Replace in word based on Database in Excel

Tags: database, excel, replace, ms-word, vba

I am looking for a way to Find and Replace text in a Word Document based on Data in Excel in excel

More specifically:

Column A = Text I want to find
Column B = Text I want to replace the found text with

I already know basic Find and Replace code in VBA, but I'm struggling to work out how to do it like this (Cross-application).

Can anyone help me?

Thanks :)

REQUESTED SCREENSHOT:

[image]

I've clipped a sample of my spreadsheet due to potentially sensitive information being displayed but this gives the jist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code needs the reference to the `MS Word 14.0 Object Library` or whatever is the equivalent on your end. If you don't want early binding, it's up to you to convert it to late binding.

```
Sub FindReplaceInWord()

    Dim Wbk As Workbook: Set Wbk = ThisWorkbook
    Dim Wrd As New Word.Application
    Dim Dict As Object
    Dim RefList As Range, RefElem As Range

    Wrd.Visible = True
    Dim WDoc As Document
    Set WDoc = Wrd.Documents.Open("C:\xxx\Doc1.docx") 'Modify as necessary.

    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set RefList = Wbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A3") 'Modify as necessary.

    With Dict
        For Each RefElem In RefList
            If Not .Exists(RefElem) And Not IsEmpty(RefElem) Then
                .Add RefElem.Value, RefElem.Offset(0, 1).Value
            End If
        Next RefElem
    End With

    For Each Key In Dict
        With WDoc.Content.Find
            .Execute FindText:=Key, ReplaceWith:=Dict(Key)
        End With
    Next Key

    'Enable the following three if you want.
    'WDoc.Save
    'WDoc.Close
    'Wrd.Quit

End Sub
```

**Screenshots:**

**`Word Document (before running code)`**

[image]

**`Reference List in Excel`**

[image]

**`Word Document (after running code)`**

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

**EDIT:**

For reference, the code doesn't have problems with your list. I think it's something else altogether. See my screenshot.

[image]

As you can see, using `Debug.Print Key, Dict(Key)` shows it's safe. I have modified the code above to change something that might be causing this. :)

Comment: Wow @BK201 Thank you. This is extremely close to what I'm looking for! The only setback is this code isn't equipped to deal with Duplicates (The index I'm using will replace some different Words with the same text) and errors with `Run-Time error '457': This Key is already associated with an element of this collection.` Any way round this? I've popped an `On Error Resume Next' in there for now, But that won't register the desired Dictionary entry.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the left hand side of the list is the word to replace and the right hand side is the replacement, yes? That basically means that you shouldn't have duplicates in the left hand side, otherwise, it's going to be replaced twice. The left side should be unique but the right side can have duplicates. Or am I missing something here? Can you post a screenshot of your reference list?

Comment: Screenshot added above... Column A is entirely Unique but column B contains a few duplicates where data is being condensed in the word documents. I stepped through the code displaying MsgBox's where it was capturing data for the dictionary and as far as I can tell, the error occurs when a duplicate is met in the referenced 'Column B'

Comment: I think I know why. :) Did you refer to the whole of Column A, by any chance? Because if so, it must be considering the blank cells as a key as well. Better to be really explicit and assign the range with a proper "end" cell. Also, changed the code above to check `If Not IsEmpty` instead of `Is Not Nothing`. That one difference is crucial. Run it this time again with the modified code above. :)

Comment: That's much better, thanks/ There is one more slight Problem however. When I run it, all my fields are deleted without being replaced by the new text - sort of. I stepped through it (which took a while) and I saw that the text was first being replaced successfully with the data in my worksheet and it appeared fine, but upon the next cycle of `.Execute FindText:=Key, ReplaceWith:=Dict(Key)` it disappeared again and was left empty. Can you think of a reason for this? My range is ok I think - set to `.Range("A1:B236")`

Comment: Set it to `.Range("A1:A236")` only. The reason for this is simple: the dictionary steps through Column A first and records the index in A and the value one column to the right of it, Column B. This is the `.Offset(0,1)` part. Now, after finishing A, it also traverses B because of the range you gave it and records whatever is in the right of B. I'm assuming C is empty, that's why it replaces the text with blanks now. :)

Comment: *Facepalm* Oh my god what an idiot. Thank you so much you're a legend!!!!!!! Works perfectly now :)

Comment: You're not. Before I totally grasped dictionaries, I had to suffer the above as well. Or maybe to be correct, we were both idiots then but not now. ;) Good luck and thanks for accepting. :)